# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from modem for certain settings

Tags: browser, dsl-modem, vdsl

I'm trying to setup my VDSL modem (Zyxel p-870H-51a v2) to connect to the internet.

Whenever I go to modify, or apply/save a connection setting, it gives me a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE/Server closed connection without sending data.

I can browse through other settings however.

Any idea of what this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had done a hardware reset, but hadn't done it properly.

To resolve it, to a full hardware reset, hold the button on for a full 15 seconds, till the power button turns off and then starts blinking.